# Flattening the AcroForm in PDFBox 2 changes font color

Tags: pdfbox

I have a pdf with a grey background on which there are few PDFields. I have set the value for these fields using:

```
PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
if(null != form){
    //Field on top of grey background
    PDField idField = form.getField("id");
    if (null != idField) {
        idField.setValue(value);
    }

    //Other fields outside grey background
}
```

Everything works as expected. However, the form fields are not visible when opening in ios' default PDF reader.  So I'm trying to flatten the pdf.

Now, when I try to flatten the pdf using `form.flatten()`, the text of the PDFields on top of the grey background become white (it was black before flattening).

And just for experimenting, I tried flattening only the other fields in the PDF (and skip flattening idField) using `form.flatten(fieldsToFlatten, false)`. When I do this, the fields on the grey background completely disappear.

Why is the font color changing when I try to flatten the pdf? Is there anyway to retain the original font color?

Thanks.

Comment: Please supply the PDF in question. Your issue might be an issue of the PDF as likely as an issue of PDFBox.

Comment: @mkl you are right. looks like there was some issue with the pdf. Creating it again fixed my problem. Thanks.